# confirmation dialog on delete button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to confirmation message dialog  when deleting the data in php. It gives me the error.
Here is my code:

```
  echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=".$row['id']."' onclick='return confirm('Are you want to delete')'>Delete</a></td>";
```

It show me the error like this :
unexpected '<' sympol in this line.But use confirm message as empty like confirm('') it gives output. It shows me empty dialog. How can i add string inside confirm('').

Comment: thank you for your suggestion...!!

Comment: I've fallen onto deaf ears, once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the wrong quotes, you have to escape single quotes:

```
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=".$row['id']."' onclick=\"return confirm('Are you want to delete')\">Delete</a></td>";
```

Comment: "Try" doesn't instruct anyone and most particularly for the person who asked the question and as to where failed and "why". There is a reason you know.

Comment: It's not that he used the _wrong_ quotes, it's that he didn't escape the quotes.

Comment: @noahnu Exactly, and "spot on" ;-)